# How to disable Visual Studio 2010 auto restart on crash?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 crashes on exit a lot for me. Often it decides to auto-restart, and if I miss the short time out to hit the cancel box it loads again.

Is there a registry key to disable this auto restart feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had reported this at Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569754/add-ability-to-disable-auto-restart-on-crash

They said it's in the next version. I happened to test the SP1 Beta and noticed that it's fixed there, so this issue will be resolved soon when SP1 releases.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a way to unregister an application specifically from (Windows's) Application Restart feature.  You can try making error reporting ask you before checking for solutions, or just exclude devenv.exe from the error reporting.  On Win7, you can find these options in the Control Panel, under `System and Security -> Action Center -> Problem Reporting Settings`.

Note that if you do exclude VS and don't send the Watson reports back, nobody on the VS team will ever see them and have a chance to fix them.  We do investigate these reports regularly, so it's always helpful to send it in if you can.

Comment: Agreed - I don't want to disable error reporting, for the reasons you state. I'll try the "ask" option instead.

Comment: Changing the option to "Ask" does prevent the auto restart. However, I now get a dialog that has three choices: Check online for a solution and restart the program, Close the program, and Debug the program. I assume that if I don't pick the first one then the watson report won't get submitted. :/

Comment: I think you are probably right; I think they combine the idea of reporting the issue and checking for a solution.  Hopefully someone else can give you a better answer than mine :(

Answer (score 1):

I also had the "crash on exit" issue in VS2010 on XP. I solved it by installing the latest Windows Updates- there was nothing specific for VS, however I've not had a crash since.